# Android Studio 4.1.3. Project View > Android stuck at Loading

Tags: android

Stuck at "Loading..." All other views are displayed quickly except Android View.

[image: Android View Stuck]

Comment: First you can try Build -> Rebuild Project if it does not work Invalidate Caches/Restart can work it works for many things

Comment: Both didnt work. Funny enough when I open gradle.build for editing in a new Android Studio window, the Android View automatically lists its contents. When I close it goes back to same prob